# RewriteRule multiple URLs in 1 subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect multiple pages to a new subdirectory.

/testme/page1 would redirect to /testmenew/page1
/testme/page2 would redirect to /testmenew/page2
etc...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$
RewriteRule ^testme/?(.*)$ http://www.url.com/testmenew/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Right now the above redirect is just pointing back to homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this rule as your very first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?url\.com$
RewriteRule ^testme(/.*)?$ /testmenew$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Also better to test it in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Thanks again! Is the NC necessary? I've been omitting it.

Comment: No NC is not necessary, it is used for ignore case comparison only.